# Translation of "according to a recent study"

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

While reading [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprache) Wikipedia article on the German language, I came across the following sentence:

> Die deutsche Gegenwartssprache umfasst einer neueren Untersuchung nach mehr als fünf Millionen Wörter.

Unless my sources have mistaken me, I believe this sentence (roughly) translates to

> According to a recent study, the contemporary German language contains more than five million words.

I am confused as to how the phrase "einer neueren Untersuchung" is functioning in this sentence. Is it in the genitive or dative case? How does it mean "according to a recent study"? In addition, I am wondering what purpose *nach* serves in this sentence.

Comment: It is actually *einer neueren Untersuchung nach* which is a bit casually (not very elegantly) expressed. You could also say *einer neueren Untersuchung zufolge* or *laut einer neueren Untersuchung*.

Comment: Ok, I suppose the fact that *nach* comes after the phrase it refers to is what confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase is four words long:

> einer neueren Studie nach

The word *"nach"* is an apposition, that normally is used as a preposition:

> nach einer neueren Studie

But it also can be used as a postposition as in your example.

The whole part of speech would be called a prepositional object (Präpositionalobjekt) if *"nach"* were the first word. I'm not sure if you call it a postpositional object here, but the grammatical function is the same.

The apposition "nach" is one of the prepositions that only can be used together with a complement in dative case. And in fact, *"einer neueren Studie"* is in dative case. You can see it, when you forget the attribute *"neueren"* for a moment:

*"Die Studie"* is a feminine word, so with an indefinite article it is:

> Nom: **Eine Studie** wurde veröffentlicht.
>   Gen: Dieser Umstand bedarf **einer Studie.**
>   Dat: Diese Erkenntnis verdanken wir **einer Studie.**
>   Akk: Ich lese gerade **eine Studie.**

Now for the Attribute *"neueren":*
Most words that are used as attributes are adjectives, and this is true in this case too. And most adjectives can appear in three degrees of comparison, and the adjective *"neu"* (*new*) is one of them:

- **positive**

  > Die Studie ist **neu.** The study is **new.**
  >   Die **neue** Studie sagt, dass Wasser flüssig ist. The **new** study says Water is liquid.
- **comparative**

  > Die Studie ist **neuer.** The study is **newer.**
  >   Die **neuere** Studie sagt, dass Wasser flüssig ist. The **newer** study says Water is liquid.
- **superlative**

  > Die Studie ist **am neuesten.** The study is **newest.**
  >   Die **neueste** Studie sagt, dass Wasser flüssig ist. The **newest** study says Water is liquid.

All adjectives that are used as attribute inside a noun group must be inflected, as you can see in the examples above. And when you combine comparative and dative case, you get:

> nach einer neueren Studie
>   according to a newer study

But in english this sounds not really satisfying, so you replace *"newer"* by *"more recent"* (which is the comparative of *"recent"*):

> according to a more recent study

But this again doesn't sound like good English, so you don't use the comparative, but the positive form:

> according to a recent study